# Why Doesn't My Foundation Tooltip Work?

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I want to use a Foundation tooltip:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tooltips.html

According to the instructions: I put this code in `body` :

```
<script>
  document.write('<script src=/js/vendor/'
    + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
    + '.js><\/script>');
</script>
```

and use:

```
<script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
```

and:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $(document).foundation();    
  })
</script>
```

and I use this code in `body`

```
<span data-tooltip class="has-tip" title="Tooltips are awesome, you should totally use them!">extended information</span>
```

But it does not work:

[image: upload.tehran98.com/img1/6taveochivfnio6ch6h2.png]

Now what do I do to have tooltip like this?

[image: upload.tehran98.com/img1/zkmxqt8nqvkbnyn4bd.png]

Comment: What does the error console tell you?

Comment: Just checking: do you have the Foundation CSS included on the page?

Comment: No I have not Foundation CSS

Comment: The tooltips won't appear correctly without the Foundation CSS: have a look at the Getting Started document on http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/ ... particularly the _HTML Page Markup_ section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't use:

```
<script src="/js/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
```

and didn't download CSS: http://foundation.zurb.com/download.php

I use them and tooltip work now:

[image]

Comment: For anyone encountering this problem in Rails (3.1+), just add this to you application.js includes section:
    //= require vendor/custom.modernizr

Answer (score 2):

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    $(document).foundation();    
  })
</script>
<span data-tooltip class="has-tip" title="Tooltips are awesome, you should totally use them!">extended information</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem as @naser and here is how I fixed my problem:

My first issue was that I did not have modernizr running on my site. In the `<head>` section of your page add Modernizr:

```
<script src="/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
```

This should work if your Foundation files are installed correctly, but for some reason mine were not. So I used the files from [CDNJS](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/foundation) to install modernizr:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.0.2/js/modernizr.js"></script>
```

If you don't want to use files from CDNJS then you should navigate to your Foundation/js folder and see if the files(modernizr.js, foundation.js, etc...) are in there. If they are not try checking the bower_components folder and then copy them over to the Foundation/js folder. If you can't find them anywhere try reinstalling Foundation.

And that worked great for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by putting modernizr.js in the foundation scripts folder and by calling the modernizr.js in the head section of the page.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/foundation/modernizr.js"></script>
```

All working charm!!